# How can I send a signal to a running jenkins job

Tags: selenium, jenkins

Our integration test runs on jenkins(with docker plugin) and selenium. When a test fails, we would like the containers still be running so we can inspect the situation. In order to prevent the containers from stopping, we have a script running an infinite loop at the end of the job when things go wrong.

When the test passes, the loop does not run which works fine.  When the test fails, the containers are still running which is good, but the job will run forever.  We have to the abort the job but the test will not be marked as failed.

So I'm wondering if one can send a signal to a failing test to break the loop and end the test normally? Sorry for the wordiness. Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `docker kill` to send signal to running container.

```
# docker kill --help

Usage:  docker kill [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Kill a running container

  --help=false         Print usage
  -s, --signal=KILL    Signal to send to the container
```

For example,there is a running container named `jenkins`.

The command is  `docker kill --signal=SIGTERM jenkins`

Note:Only one process which pid=1 in the container can receive this signal.